# How to run as admin an .Net exe with PSExec ( doesn't work on some of EXE)

Tags: windows, psexec, sysinternals

I use PsExec to run some exe with administrators right on a Windows Server 2016.
It works.

Saddly, i have a .net exe which run not in admin right despite the use of psExec. I think it's due to the exe itself. Anyone know a workaround ?

**Here is my bat :**

```
start /wait D:\PsExec.exe -i -d -accepteula -u XXXX\admin -p YYYYYYYYY D:\folder\myExe.exe
```

My exe launch itself, but not with admin right :(
Others exe run in admin with no issues.

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot